# How to disable type checking for test file in Visual Code Studio

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, typechecking

I am currently write some tests for my angular application. When I mock class to check if method is correctly called, I make a mock implementation. When I do that my code is underlined with red dots because my mock does not respect the true implementation of the type.

Here is an example. Here I want mock HttpLink class in order to test that create function is called. I dont mind how HttpLink object is construct. So I mocked HttpLink class and I mock create function. But visual studio code put red dot when I call the constructor because it does not respect the true HttpLink implementation :

```
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular'
jest.mock('apollo-angular', () => {
  return {
    Apollo: () => {
      return {
        create: jest.fn()
      }
    }
  }
})
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-angular-link-http'
jest.mock('apollo-angular-link-http', () => {
  return {
    HttpLink: () => {
      return {
        create: jest.fn()
      }
    }
  }
})
import { GraphqlService } from './graphql.service'

describe('GraphqlService', () => {
  let apollo = new Apollo()
  let httpLink = new HttpLink() // <====== This is red because type checking see this class need one argument but I mocked the constructor.
  let graphqlService
  beforeAll(() => {
    graphqlService = new GraphqlService(apollo, httpLink)
  })

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(graphqlService).toBeTruthy()
  })

  it('should create apollo client correctly', () => {
    expect(apollo.create).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Is there a way to desactivate type checking that visual studio code does, but only for test files ?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the preferences and then Settings

In User Settings, you have to update following :

```
"typescript.validate.enable": true,
```

to

```
"typescript.validate.enable": false,
```

Hope it will help you !!